# Onyx: Can't pick up trigger/emit results in the next task

Tags: clojure, onyx-platform

I'm trying to get started with [Onyx](http://www.onyxplatform.org/), the distributed computing platform in Clojure. In particular, I try to understand how to aggregate data. If I understand the documentation correctly, a combination of a [window](http://www.onyxplatform.org/docs/user-guide/0.10.x/#windowing-and-aggregation) and a [`:trigger/emit` function](http://www.onyxplatform.org/docs/cheat-sheet/latest/#trigger-entry/:trigger/emit) should allow me to do this.

So, I modified the [aggregation example](https://github.com/onyx-platform/onyx-examples/tree/0.13.x/aggregation) (Onyx 0.13.0) in three ways (cf. gist with [complete code](https://gist.github.com/schaueho/1e0bb52c1b14799304b45ed05a98f382)):

- in `-main` I `println` any segments put on the output channel; this works as expected with the original code in that it picks up all segments and prints them to stdout.
- I add an emit function like this:

  ```
  (defn make-ds
     [event window trigger {:keys [lower-bound upper-bound event-type] :as state-event} extent-state]
     (println "make-ds called")
     {:ds window})
  ```
- I add a trigger configuration (original `dump-words` trigger emitted for brevity):

  ```
  (def triggers
   [{:trigger/window-id :word-counter
     :trigger/id :make-ds
     :trigger/on :onyx.triggers/segment
     :trigger/fire-all-extents? true
     :trigger/threshold [5 :elements]
     :trigger/emit ::make-ds}])
  ```
- I change the `:count-words` task to from calling the `identity` function to the `reduce` type, so that it doesn't hand over all input segments to the output (and added config options that onyx should tackle this as a batch):

  ```
      {:onyx/name :count-words
       ;:onyx/fn :clojure.core/identity
       :onyx/type :reduce ; :function
       :onyx/group-by-key :word
       :onyx/flux-policy :kill
       :onyx/min-peers 1
       :onyx/max-peers 1
       :onyx/batch-size 1000
       :onyx/batch-fn? true}
  ```

When I run this now, I can see in the output that the emit function (i.e. `make-ds`) gets called for each input segment (first output coming from the `dump-words` trigger of the original code):

```
     > lein run
     [....]
     Om -> 1
     name -> 1
     My -> 2
     a -> 1
     gone -> 1
     Coffee -> 1
     to -> 1
     get -> 1
     Time -> 1
     make-ds called
     make-ds called
     make-ds called
     make-ds called
     [....]
```

However, the segment build from make-ds doesn't make it through to the output-channel, they are never being printed. If I revert the `:count-words` task to the `identity` function, this works just fine. Also, it looks as if the emit function is called for each input segment, whereas I would expect it to be called only when the threshold condition is true (i.e. whenever 5 elements have been aggregated in the window).

As the test for this functionality within the Onyx code base (`onyx.windowing.emit-aggregate-test`) is passing just fine, I guess I'm making a stupid mistake somewhere, but I'm at a loss figuring out what.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

I finally saw that there was a warning in the log file `onxy.log` like this:

```
[clojure.lang.ExceptionInfo: Windows cannot be checkpointed with ZooKeeper unless 
  :onyx.peer/storage.zk.insanely-allow-windowing? is set to true in the peer config.
  This should only be turned on as a development convenience.
[clojure.lang.ExceptionInfo: Handling uncaught exception thrown inside task 
  lifecycle :lifecycle/checkpoint-state. Killing the job. -> Exception type: 
  clojure.lang.ExceptionInfo. Exception message: Windows cannot be checkpointed with
  ZooKeeper unless :onyx.peer/storage.zk.insanely-allow-windowing? is set to true   in
  the peer config. This should only be turned on as a development convenience.
```

As soon as I set this, I finally got some segments handed over to the next task. I.e., I had to change the peer config to:

```
(def peer-config
  {:zookeeper/address "127.0.0.1:2189"
   :onyx/tenancy-id id
   :onyx.peer/job-scheduler :onyx.job-scheduler/balanced
   :onyx.peer/storage.zk.insanely-allow-windowing? true
   :onyx.messaging/impl :aeron
   :onyx.messaging/peer-port 40200
   :onyx.messaging/bind-addr "localhost"})
```

Now, `:onyx.peer/storage.zk.insanely-allow-windowing?` doesn't sound like a good thing to do. Lucas Bradstreet recommended on the Clojurians Slack channel switching to S3 checkpointing.